# Azure Application Gateway Redirection from empty hostname

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network, f5, azure-application-gateway

I have created an Application Gateway that needs to fulfill the working of my previous Resource (F5).

```
As a listener I use a hostname: hostname.stackoverflow.com that listens on 443

As a Http Setting I am using a specific port being 4443 

As a BackEnd pool I use the URL/FQDN of my dev VM.
```

This totally works If i create a VM in the VNET and add "hostname.stackoverflow.com" to the hosts file with the ip of the application gateway.

Now I want to get a little further and add paths to my Application Gateway. 
The goal is that if I use "hostname.stackoverflow.com" I need to redirect this to "Hostname.stackoverflow.com/login.aspx?guestlogin".

As far I have tried the following.

- Add the "/login.aspx?guestLogin" to the HTTPS settings like this.
  [image]

When I try this inside my VM. The URL changes but the path that I added there was not added in the right way, This is what I got: 
[image]

So That made me think override backend path is maybe not the right way to do this.
Wanted To create a Redirection Rule That will redirect my "hostname.stackoverflow.com" to the "hostname.stackoverflow.com/login.aspx?guestLogin" But in the settings of the Application Gateway I need to provide a source path (meaning: I can not redirect from an empty hostname to a new url I think)

I am very new to Azure and even more new to the Application Gateway. Is there something that I did wrong. Is there a better way to do this ?

The iRule that I need to get in Application Gateway is as followed.

```
  if { [string tolower [HTTP::host]] equals "hostname.stackoverflow.com" } {

        if {[HTTP::path] eq "/"} {
                 HTTP::redirect "login.aspx?guestLogin"
    }
    elseif {[string tolower [HTTP::uri]] starts_with "/login.aspx?id="} {
                 set tail [string range [HTTP::uri] 12 end]
                 HTTP::redirect "login.aspx?guestLogin&$tail"
    }
  pool default.pool
  }
```

Comment: i dont think application gateway can do that, it can only change root path, not append to it

Comment: So the only way to do this. is in IIS to redirect on that fase and not before when the route left the application gateway.

Comment: well, not the only way, but one way to do it would be using IIS redirect.

Comment: Do you have a better way in mind ? 
or can you guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: well, you can use other routing solution after application gateway or before. perhaps azure front door

Comment: Can you explain why override backend path did not work when I added this to the rule ?
There is no backend path and with the http setting it overrides the empty one with a new one. Or do I see this wrongly ?

I will look at a rooting solution and search into the Azure Frontdoor resource

Comment: i might be wrong about application gateway routing, but i dont see why this wont work unless it doesnt work in principle

Comment: Thanks for your insight. You answer a lot of my and other questions that are about Azure. Appreciate your help a lot !!!.

Comment: FYI: I think it is possible; but messy/not worth it... First you'd need to set your site with backend settings pointing to `/login.aspx?guestLogin` so that anyone hitting the root gets sent there.  On its own that would send other requests there too (e.g. `mysite.com/Welcome.html` would go to `mysite.com/login.aspx?guestLogin/Welcome.html`.  To avoid that, you'd need to add additional path based rules for each path (or pattern) that shouldn't be redirected.  Sadly you can't do it the other way round (e.g. having `/` redirect) as that matches all paths (pattern is the start of path not regex)